# How do I resolve the feud between Trumbel and Sweynur?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

I'm doing the "Against the grain" quest at the moment. I've talked to Sweynour, I've talked to the miller Trumbel. I talked to them again. I'm supposed to somehow resolve the conflict, but I only get the same dialoge options I already exhausted again. I'm supposed to convince Sweynour that the miller doesn't have any grain stashed away, but I only get the option to tell him that I'll talk to the miller, which I already did.

Am I missing some step here in solving the issue? What do I have to do to advance the quest?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to talk to Pasca (the innkeeper/bartender) to order drinks for the famers. Took me quite a while to find that one. I was just carrying beer and ale in my inventory and wondering why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

If your stats are high enough, you can resolve the quest in other ways. Might 16 allows you to pick up Sweynur and threaten him, and Dexterity 16 allows you to put a blade against his throat. You can also Attack him. I didn't try that one, but I suspect it would have resolved things, albeit with some consequences.